# Improve description of Pundit badge

Tags: feature-request, comment-badges

I don't find [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/40/pundit) clear:

> Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more

I would prefer:

> Left 10 comments, each with a score of 5 or more

Comment: Copy paste error that cost you 3 downvotes.. I always read twice my question after posting it to make sure I don't have such typos. Anyhow,  minor change but can't see any harm doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I think that is rather improbable 5 is the total score of the 10 comments, considering that the badge is a silver badge; that would mean a score of at least 0.5 for each comment.
Considering also that there is a [bronze badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/31/commentator) for leaving 10 comments, it's more probable the score is referring to the score for each comment.

There is no need to change the description; many of the badge descriptions are intentionally open to more than one interpretation. The reason is that badges should be a surprise, not something you exactly know when you get them. (At least this is the description somebody else used for the badges.)

Jeff Atwood, in [A Bevy of New Badges](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/a-bevy-of-new-badges/) says:

> Badges are supposed to be a little mysterious; you should view them as minor puzzles with obvious hints.

Comment: When one realizes that "with score 5 or more" doesn't refer to total score, one will slap one's own face with one's hand and say to oneself, "Aw, shucks", and move on.

Comment: Do you have a reference to *many of the badge descriptions are intentionally open to more than one interpretation*? It's the first I've heard of it.

Comment: @Tshepang The reference to that would be the description of many badges; if you read many of them, it's not immediately clear when you get those badges.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: But that does not necessarily mean they were intentionally meant to be vague.

Comment: @Tshepang That is not what Jeff seems to think.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Oh, I didn't notice that you did. I didn't get a notification :)